# Swing and inheritance

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have two classes one extending another. In both of them i have fields representing swing components. The problem is that something is wrong when i try to use components from child class - it seems Swing thread does not have access to child components. What am i doing wrong?

```
public abstract class AppViewBase {
    protected JPanel jContentPane = null;

    protected void initialize() {
        //...
        addOutputControlls(jContentPane);
        //...
    }
    protected abstract void addOutputControlls(JPanel jContentPane) ;
}

public class Titrai extends AppViewBase  {
    public JTextPane line1 = null;
    public JTextPane line2 = null;

    protected void addOutputControlls(JPanel jContentPane2) {
        jContentPane2.add(getJTextPane());
        jContentPane2.add(getJTextPane2());
    }

    public void setCurrentLine(Object selectedValue) {
        String s = (String) selectedValue;
        getJTextPane().setText(s);
        getJTextPane2().setText("");

        getJTextPane().repaint();
        //only gets repainted i i move line1, line2 fields to parent class
        getJTextPane2().repaint();
    }

}
```

---

**Edit - Code from comment**

```
if(EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) { 
  initialize(); 
} else { 
  try { 
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { 
       @Override 
       public void run() { 
         initialize(); 
       } 
    }); 
  } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

---

**Edit 2 - Code From OP's Other Comment**

```
  JTextPane getJTextPane() {
     if (line1 == null) {
        line1 = new JTextPane();
        line1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        line1.setForeground(Color.white);
        line1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(385, 16));
        line1.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, false);
        line1.setEditorKit(getDefaultLineEditorKit());
        line1.setEditable(false);
        line1.setLocation(new Point(15, 15));
        line1.setSize(new Dimension(385, 16));
        line1.setBackground(Color.black);
        line1.setFocusable(false);
        line1.setBorder(null);
     }
     return line1;
  }
```

Comment: There is no such limitation. The only limitation is that ALL changes to the GUI must be done on the EDT. Are you doing this?

Comment: my GUI initialization is like this:
if(EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
   initialize();
  } else {
   try {
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      initialize();
     }
    });
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

Comment: What does `getJTextPane()` do/return, where is it defined? Same for `getJTextPane2()`.

Comment: it sets line1 and line2 fields and returns JTextPane

Comment: the before mentioned initialization code was run from constructor, i've moved it out of constructor and now there is no problem anymore :) but the question remains - why parent class initialization was run in EDT and child initialization - not?

Comment: It sets line1? Show the code please.

Comment: JTextPane getJTextPane() {
  if (line1 == null) {
   line1 = new JTextPane() ;
   line1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
   line1.setForeground(Color.white);
   line1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(385, 16));
   line1.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, false);
   line1.setEditorKit(getDefaultLineEditorKit());
   line1.setEditable(false);
   line1.setLocation(new Point(15, 15));
   line1.setSize(new Dimension(385, 16));
   line1.setBackground(Color.black);
   line1.setFocusable(false);
   line1.setBorder(null);
  }
  return line1;
 }

Comment: How do you know child initialization doesn't run in EDT? What debugger told you that?

Comment: well, that was just my guess... now i've moved initialization out of special EDT checking and it still works. so, it seems, swing initialization in constructor was causing a mess. And now initialization takes place in main thread, not EDT - that's what debugger told me

Comment: I assume somewhere in `//...` you are initializing that `JPanel`?

Comment: You can better move all of your code to the EDT, so the only thing you do in `main` is 'switching' to the EDT. Concurrency is hard, so keep it simple. Glad you solved it anyway.

Comment: You aren't calling `addOutputControlls` from the `AppViewBase` constructor are you? Because when the `Titrai` constructor is called, you initialisers will reset the fields.

Comment: You can't show code in the comments section here as you lose all formatting. You must edit your original post and show the new or updated code there.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... As I can see you don't init this field as

```
protected JPanel jContentPane = null;
```

I guess you should modify the field code as

```
protected JPanel jContentPane = new JPanel();
```

...because null is not the "ready to be used" object value :)

I mean this method ...

```
protected void initialize() {
        //...
        addOutputControlls(jContentPane);//<-- contain null 
        //...
    }
```

...is seemed to work with null panel so the init is not done correctly.

Good luck :)